# Several ways to call "use"?

Tags: clojure

What's the difference between `(use 'korma.db)` and `(:use korma.db)`?

Functionally they seem to do the same thing, but one looks like it's a function call and the other is dereferencing a map? Why two ways of writing it and how do they end up doing the same thing?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(:use ...)` form is a directive passed to ns, not a dereference of a map. ns is a macro, so things in an ns form are not evaluated in the standard way. The :use directive in an ns form causes ns to invoke (use ...).

Since "use" has an effect on all evaluations done in the ns where you invoke it, it makes sense to specify it in the context of declaring the namespace rather than randomly invoking it somewhere else in ones code.

Comment: Ah, I see. So using `(:use ...)` actually invokes use *only* in that namespace because it's a directive passed to the macro, while using `(use '...)` invokes it in place (and so it used for the repl)?

Comment: use only affects the current namespace, but its action is so closely tied to the namespace where it is invoked, that it is best to invoke it as part of the namespace definition. Really what use does is modify the rules for looking up definitions in a namespace, so why do that separately from the definition of the namespace it modifies? Also, :use is generally considered deprecated, it is better to use :require with a :refer argument (use tends to make code harder to read, because it is not immediately obvious where a given function may have been defined).